# How to Show Duplicate Column Records only one time in Order by Function in SQL

Tags: mysql, h2

Due to Great support from [Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen), i finally got this, i want to make it little bit more look feel removing the Duplicates while ordering the `Customer`. But i dont want the `Customer` to be duplicate.

My output is this:

Query:

```
SELECT Customer, Product, Price
FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT Customer, 'Total', SUM(Price)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Customer
UNION ALL
SELECT '', 'Grand Total', SUM(Price)
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Customer = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
         Customer,
         CASE WHEN Product = 'Total' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
         Product;
```

This is the Output i got with Above Query

```
Customer    Product       Price 
  -------------------------------
  Suryam      Shampo        100
  Suryam      Rubber        150
  Suryam      Glass         250
  Suryam      Total         500----->Total
  Raghu       Bottel        60  
  Raghu       Biscuit       180
  Raghu       Total         240----->Total
              Grand Total   740----->Grand Total
```

But i want this if it is possible:

```
 Customer    Product       Price 
---------------------------------
  Suryam      Shampo        100
              Rubber        150
              Glass         250
              Total         500----->Total
  Raghu       Bottel        60  
              Biscuit       180
              Total         240----->Total
              Grand Total   740----->Grand Total
```

Comment: Rollup yes.. But nulling out values in its own group... That is something you should consider doing in your application code.

Comment: what exactly do you want as output?

Comment: Am using Java Swing GUI to show this Similay Query in JTable, could you help

Comment: Quesion updated

Comment: Directly a query for above doesn't make sense and i think it is not possible; anyways, is it not possible for you to do something similar to what you want before displaying?

Comment: do you have a test data before it returns at your query sample?